# Highcharts showing timestamp as wrong date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I need to show correct date on highcharts based on timestamp,

Config as follows,

```
series: [{
  "name": "avg_sales",
  "color": "#3b6982",
  "data": [{
      "name": 1230768000,
      "y": 526.4200000000001
    }, {
      "name": 1230854400,
      "y": 1850.3116666666667
    }, {
      "name": 1230940800,
      "y": 3199.786
    }]
}],
tooltip: {
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    hour: '%A, %b %e, %l %p'
  },
},
xAxis: {
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {
  hour: '%A, %b %e, %l %p'
  },
  type: 'datetime'
}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
it shows correct values in tooltip but not in the x axis values. how to sort this issue?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/95LX7/70/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use timestamp or number, use x property instead of name (name can be still used though but x takes precedence)

```
"data": [{
        "name": "point's name",
      "x": 1230768000,
      "y": 526.4200000000001
    }, {
      "x": 1230854400,
      "y": 1850.3116666666667
    }, {
      "x": 1230940800,
      "y": 3199.786
    }]
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/95LX7/71/

Answer (score 1):

One way is to change data format to following as what shown in [highchart official example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series)

```
  "data": [
    [1230768000, 526.4200000000001],
    [1230854400, 1850.3116666666667],
    [1230940800, 3199.786]
  ]
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95LX7/71/)